# How to make MouseClicked event work in java

Tags: java, swing, events, mouseevent

I am pretty sure this is very easy and that I am only missing one line or two but I just cannot make this work despite searching for solutions over the internet. I am fairly new to java and my problem is in a desktop application.

I have a pretty simple desktop application with one text area, one menu bar with one menu and 3 menu item. I want to edit the text of the text area when I click on the Statistic menu item in a JFrame.

Here is the part of the code where I create the menu bar, menu and menu items (as well as their events):

```
//menu
        mnuRevision.setText("Revision");

    mnuitmStats.setText("Statistique");
    mnuitmStats.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            mnumnuitmStatsMouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });
    mnuRevision.add(mnuitmStats);

    mnuitmOrthographe.setText("Grammaire et orthographe");
    mnuitmOrthographe.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            mnuitmOrthographeMouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });
    mnuRevision.add(mnuitmOrthographe);

    mnuitmAnalyse.setActionCommand("Analyse");
    mnuitmAnalyse.setText("Analyse");
    mnuRevision.add(mnuitmAnalyse);

    jMenuBar1.add(mnuRevision);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);
```

Here is the Mousclicked function:

```
    private void mnumnuitmStatsMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt){
        this.txtTexte.setText("asdf");
        this.repaint();

    }
```

What I want to do is when I click on **mnuitemStats**, the **txtTexte** will get the text **"asdf"** written in it. Somehow, this is not working. It looks like the program is not even getting into the function. I looked on some tutorials and they pretty much have the same code as me except for the objects names since most tutorials uses **JButton** instead of **JMenuItem**.

I can provide my whole code if it is needed, but I thought the rest would be irrelevant since it does not touch the menu bar or the textarea. I am using Eclipse Java EE IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually write something like

```
mnuitemStats.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {// your logic here;
    }});
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming mnuitmStats is a JMenuItem, it should be.  A little more code would be helpful but given that assumption you should use ActionListener not a MouseListener for this.

Something like:

```
class MenuActionListener implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //do something

  }
}
```

and

```
JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
menuBar.add(fileMenu);

JMenuItem newMenuItem = new JMenuItem("New");
newMenuItem.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
fileMenu.add(newMenuItem);
```